# How can I completely remove python on Windows 10 for a new installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

So I recently had to change my user folder name in Windows 10 and now python doesnt' seem to work anymore. I can't start it from the command line and idle doesn't work. Can anybody help me completely remove it from my system so I can do a new installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
to uninstall python. Even if the installation is broken, it usually manages
to clean up after the program.

Then search for all folders on the computer containing the string "python",
and delete them carefully (not to delete your own folders).

Now you can install python and use it again.